# Breakable parbox at the end of page

Tags: page-breaking, parbox

if I'll do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\parbox{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[1-20]}
\end{document}
```

it outputs
[image]

Is there any way to get a breakable parbox? If not, I will need something different. In that specific setting I only need to do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Proof}\par
\noindent\hspace{5mm}\parbox{\columnwidth-10mm}{\lipsum[1-20]}\\
$_{}$\hfill$\square$
\end{document}
```

Ty'all.

Comment: Or `mdframed` as well.

Comment: I did it with mdframed actually. Ty

Answer (score 3):

For those already invested in `tcolorbox` (and those yet to make up their minds):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=white,colframe=white]
  \lipsum[1-20]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
going to tcolorbox or mdframed. Possible solution is offered through:

```
\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=5mm, linewidth=0pt, skipbelow=0pt]
text
\end{mdframed}
```